# Не могу понять как работает логическое ИЛИ ||

Tags: javascript, логические-выражения

Я думаю, что переменной max должно быть присвоено значение 500, а у max значение undefined

```js
var max_width = undefined;
var preference = {
      max_width: undefined;
}
var max = max_width || preferences.max_width || 500;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас рабочий код, если убрать `;` в строке `max_width: undefined;`, а так же `preferences` заменить на `preference`.

```js
var max_width = undefined;
var preference = {
      max_width: undefined
}
var max = max_width || preference.max_width || 500;

console.log(max);
```